# How do i make an automatic file writing system?

Tags: batch-file

i'm making a automatic file writing system that writes random numbers onto a .txt file, I need it to also write .bat, the problem is I'm a newbie a batch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common problem, I like to call it the autosave, this is the code:

```
(
  echo %YourVariable%
) > Mylittlevariable.sav
```

What does it do? What it does is when the script reaches this code, it writes the number for %YourVariable% in a .sav file, the .sav can easily be changed to .txt or another format.
I want it to load the variable now! The code:

```
< Mylittlevariable.sav (
  set /p YourVariable=
)
```

Well I want it to write random numbers! This is a code for random numbers:

```
(
  echo %random%
  echo %random%
) > Random#s.txt
```

So now we get how this works? Now the batch file, before having a command in an autosave batch writer you have to put an `echo`, just how `echo` makes a statement in the cmd, it types everything after it in an autosave, too. The code for a basic .bat:

```
(
  echo @echo off
  echo title Basic Autosave Batch
  echo :LOOP
  echo set SUPERVAR=15
  echo cls
  echo echo Hello, world!
  echo echo SUPERVAR: %%SUPERVAR%%
  echo pause
  echo goto LOOP
) > Mybasicbatch.bat
```

So, know we know what this does, correct? I hope I helped you!
PS the double amount of percent signs is necessary, if you had the normal amount the code wouldn't be read properly!